# Input in C merge with the next one with Struct in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef struct Student
{
    char name[256];
    char id[5];
    char number[10];
} Student;

Student add()
{
    Student student;
    printf("Input name: ");
    scanf("%s", student.name);
    printf("Input id: ");
    scanf("%s", student.id);
    printf("Input number: ");
    scanf("%s", student.number);
    return student;
}

int main()
{
    Student s = add();
    printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", s.name, s.id, s.number);
}
```

I got the second input merge with the third one. Anyone know how to deal with it? Please help me. Thank you very much
These are my output.
Thank you all very much. I'm sorry for my question is not clear

> Input name: khoi
> Input id: abcde
> Input number: 1234567890
> khoi                abcde1234567890     1234567890

Comment: *"These are my output"* - ok. And what is your specific *question* ?

Comment: The string "1234567890" can not be stored in an array of size 10.  You have invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: Nor can `"abcde"` be stored in an array of 5. No space for the terminator.

Comment: You must *never* use `"%s"` in scanf without a width specifier.  In this case, use `scanf("%9s", student.number)`.  The width specifier indicates the number of bytes consumed by scanf and must be no larger than one less than the size of the buffer, to allow space for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give one more room for null terminator in these two variables in given struct:

```
char id[5];
char number[10];
```

To add one, simply add one more in the lengths:

```
char id[6];
char number[11];
```

And you'll get your desired output:

```
Input name: khoi     
Input id: abcde
Input number: 1234567890
khoi                abcde               1234567890
```

---

Also note that specifying the width in `scanf()` won't make your program worse, it accepts limited user input so chances of problems to happen in a program is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The C language use so called C strings where your text is followed by null byte. E.g. to store 5 characters string `"hello"`, you would use 6 bytes and store `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`, see:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/

You can work with fixed size string without the null terminator but you need to specify the length all the time you are writing the string and using it:

https://wiki.c2.com/?NonNullTerminatedString

The reason why your `id` field is concatenated with the `number` is the fact that the null temrinator of `id` is saved to the first character of the `number` and then the `number` is written over it.

Solution is to use large enough string as you did with the name and also specify the width as [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) advised.